# webview how to send image file to the server or upload file?

Tags: android, webview, android-file

I'm using webview and access to the gallery image file. 
my question is  
1) How am I suppose to send or upload this image file to the server or upload?
2) which one should I send it

Here is My onActivityResult and got Bitmap file from the gallery .

```
  @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
        if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE){
           if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != intent){
               Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();
               web.loadUrl("javascript:setFileUri('" + selectedImage.toString() + "')");
               String path = getRealPathFromURI(this, selectedImage);
               web.loadUrl("javascript:setFilePath('" + path + "')");


               BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
               options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
               Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path,options);


               ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
               bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
               byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
               String imageBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
               String image = "data:image/png;base64," + imageBase64;
               String temp = "./img/logo.png";
               web.loadUrl("javascript:setImage('"+ image  +"')");
               //Iview01.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
               //saveBitmaptoJpeg(bitmap,"img","temp",web,path);


           }
        }
    }
```